# SQL query where

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have question about sql query
I use
`select * from where` 
I like to know how to create a SQLitle query with the teams who win and possible_win %.
table is simple.

Team1,Team2,Team1_gols,Team2_gols,Team1_possible,Team2_possible

Table data is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cBji.jpg)

answer be only
team who win and possible win less 50

Comment: Please format the data in the question correctly

Comment: and it would be really helpful if you can post table data as well

Comment: I add table picture. I need know all winners and then i need all winner who is under 50% possible

Comment: According to the data that you provided, the following should be your output right?
 Montreal Canadiens
Detroit Red Wings

Comment: Please edit to 1) have a properly formatted table, as text, not as an image (see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important); 2) show your work, and the issue you're having - currently your question is just a requirement with no effort shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where
(V_G > H_G and Possible_win_V <50)  -- V_G Won & Possibility of winning < 50
OR
(H_G > V_G and Possible_win_H <50); -- H_G Won & Possibility of winning < 50
```

Comment: Please don't answer someone's assignment, when they haven't shown any work. The OP needs to edit their question and show the issue(s) they are having. This isn't the place for people to post an assignment and have others answer that assignment for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (Team1_gols > Team2_gols AND Team1_possible < 50) -- team 1 wins with < 50 probability
      OR
      (Team1_gols < Team2_gols AND Team2_possible < 50) -- team 2 wins with < 50 probability
```

Comment: Please don't answer someone's assignment, when they haven't shown any work. The OP needs to edit their question and show the issue(s) they are having. This isn't the place for people to post an assignment and have others answer that assignment for them.